# Array of Bitmap from array in xml file

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap

I have in my array.xml an array of more than 100 images with all different name.

```
<array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/setting</item>
        <item>@drawable/simplemode</item>
...
```

I need to load all them inside an array of Bitmap
How can I do? Thanks

Comment: in your icons array you have references to the bitmaps. you can loop through the array and load them. Anyway, if you need to just set the bitmaps, for example, in an imageView, the reference will be enough. how are you going to use those bitmaps?

Comment: I just update the question. Anyway I need to modifiy and display the bitmaps. That I don't know is how to pass all the array inside the bitmap.

Comment: Please paste some code of what you have tried.

Comment: I triend many things, but when something doesn't work, I delete it. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resources arrays that contains references to Drawables are called TypedArray in Android.

You can refer to them very easily. Here's an example:

```
TypedArray icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
```

Not, icons can retrieve the drawables for you. You can find the reference here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray

For example, you could know how many drawables are references in that array with:

```
icons.length()
```

or you can get the drawable at the first position with:

```
icons.getDrawable(0);
```

Comment: I use already that; I can not anymore, because I create new array runtime and is not possible to use TypedArray.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you create in runtime? Is it not in your arrays.xml file? Please, elaborate, cannot help you without further informations

Comment: I create an array in runtime because I need to modify the images inside of it. I'd like to load this array of bitmap with the images in the array from xml file.